# Confusion about ems in media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, font-size

### One source

In Keith J. Grant's [*CSS in Depth*](https://www.manning.com/books/css-in-depth), section 8.2 I read

> it's a better idea to use ems in your media queries, based on the browser's default font size (usually 16px).

I'm tempted to understand that `em`s in media queries ***are*** based on the browser's default font size, please correct me if I'm wrong, otherwise the sentence would imply that I am responsible for requesting that the `em` be based on that font size, and nothing in the [sample code](https://github.com/CSSInDepth/css-in-depth/blob/eb5a851c5684168fe7c63db4bce0245786f11fda/ch08/listing-8.07.html#L57-L61) suggests anything like that.

### Another source

On the other hand, from the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/CR-mediaqueries-4-20200721/) I read

> EXAMPLE 27
>
> […]
>
> ```
> @media (min-width: 20em) { … }
> ```
>
> The `em` value is relative to the initial value of [`font-size`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#propdef-font-size).

and if I click on that link, I'm brought to the definition of the `font-size` property where I read that it's initial value is `medium`.

### My interpretation

- The first source says that `1em` in `@media` queries is the browser's default font size;
- The second source says that `1em` is the `initial` value of `font-size`.

### My question

Are the two sources saying the same thing? How do the two definition relate to the `rem` unit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In normal situations, `1em` is a relative unit, and in a font-size it's relative to the font-size of its parent element. `medium` is an absolute unit. In different browsers it can be set to different pixel sizes, and is chosen to be comfortable to read on a device. A common value for medium is 16px, but other values could be chosen. For example, a user might configure their browser to use a different px value for medium so that they can read the text better.

In *media queries*, there is no parent element for `1em` to be relative to. So it takes the initial value of `medium`.

So yes, the two sources are saying the same thing, the spec with just a little more precision.

The `rem` unit plays no part in this. If you use `rem` in your media query, it will also evaluate to `medium`. i.e. It would not be affected by any font size assigned to the root element in your styling.

Comment: I don't understand one thing. Is `medium` _the_ default size of the browser? I mean, if I set the default size of the browser to 14px, is that the value of `medium`? And if I don't change it but just zoom in?

Comment: `medium` is the _initial_ value of font-size. This is in the CSS _definition_. It's not necessarily the _default_ size, which could be set by the user-agent style sheet, and if it was, it wouldn't affect the value used for the media query. But this is what I mean about precision. Browsers don't in practice have a different setting in the user-agent style sheet, so they _effectively_ amount to the same thing. If you set the font-size in the browser settings, then yes, that would be the pixel size of medium. The effect of zooming is complex enough to be a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will clarify your understanding:

> 1em is equal to the current font-size of the element in question. If
> you haven’t set font size anywhere on the page, then it would be the
> browser default, which is probably 16px. So by default 1em = 16px.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

> While em is relative to the font size of its direct or nearest parent, rem is only relative to the html (root) font-size.

Source: https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/